What is the difference how React and Vue handle SVG?
I am refactoring an React app moving to Vue. When in React, SVG components works fine, in Vue, I cannot reduce its size. For me the code looks the same and I cannot find any difference. Any clue why the icons shown are different?
React part
// Icon.tsx
const Icon = React.memo(({ fill = 'black' }: Props) => {
  return (
    <div
      className={`icon-wrapper`}
    >
      <svg viewBox='0 0 1000 1000'>
        <path
          d='M990,500L663.3,227.8v163.3H282.2v217.8h381.1v163.3L990,500z M118.9,118.9h435.6V10H118.9C59,10,10,59,10,118.9v762.2C10,941,59,990,118.9,990h435.6V881.1H118.9V118.9L118.9,118.9z'
          fill={fill}
        />
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
});


https://codepen.io/franciscojaviermartin/pen/eYwgzdY
Vue part
<template>
  <div class="icon-wrapper" :style="{ pointerEvents: 'none' }">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" view-box="0 0 1000 1000">
      <path
        d="M990,500L663.3,227.8v163.3H282.2v217.8h381.1v163.3L990,500z M118.9,118.9h435.6V10H118.9C59,10,10,59,10,118.9v762.2C10,941,59,990,118.9,990h435.6V881.1H118.9V118.9L118.9,118.9z"
        :fill="fill"
      />
    </svg>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
const fill = 'black';
</script>


https://codepen.io/franciscojaviermartin/pen/rNEjLaB
General styles (same for both)
// General styles
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;

  .icon-wrapper {
    width: 40px;
  }
}


In vue you are using view-box="0 0 1000 1000" Change this to viewBox="0 0 1000 1000"

I swear I've checked that several times. That's the mistake. Thank you very much.
